# How to extract multivolume RAR with Sevenzip.pas?

Tags: delphi, callback, 7zip

I am using [Progdigy's SevenZip](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13) unit to extract RAR files. Works great when RARs are single volume. When I have a multivolume archive then it fails. I am guessing I should add some code to support a callback function which asks for another volume or something, but I am not sure how to do it. Seems it's not supported by SevenZip.pas.
I found something named ArchiveOpenVolumeCallback but no idea how to use it properly. Any help here?

Comment: An example how to use `ArchiveOpenVolumeCallback` in Java (with comments) for multivolume archives can be found here: [VolumedArchiveInStream.java](http://www.koders.com/java/fid548DFEE534CD3CC83305858E611BD95418D8ABD1.aspx?s=Access#L14).

Comment: @LURD: I don't know Java, but seems it's the only answer I can get, so thanks for that.